# Como criar tabela com java swing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Eu tenho um botão, quando eu clicar nele eu quero que apareça uma tabela com duas coluna, um será um contador e a outra um campo vazio. O numero de linhas será conforme uma variável a ser passado para a tabela. O usuário irar preencher essa segunda coluna.
Depois quero guardar os valores que o usuário digitou em uma string.
Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em azul seria o que o usuário digitaria e em preto que já iria vim com a tabela.
Alguém sabem como fazer isso ?

Comment: Sua duvida já foi respondida na pergunta marcada. Se quiser algo mais espeficico, precisa editar sua pergunta e fornecer um **[mcve]** para que se possa simular o problema.

Comment: Vejo que você é novo no site, recomendo que visite o **[tour]** para conhecer como este site funciona e leia tambem o **[ask]** para saber como elaborar boas perguntas.